# Unable to append data to existing data

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master data set with some data on it already. I'm trying to append additional data from another Excel sheet into this master data set by matching the column names and copy pasting corresponding data into my master file which I'm unable to do.

My master data set has the data in a different order from that of my new data that I need appended. So my code looks for matching headers in target (master data set) and source (new data in Excel)  and tries to copy and paste corresponding values under matching columns.

```vb
Sub AppendData()

' AppendData Macro

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' create worksheet objects
Dim shtSource As Worksheet
Dim shtTarget As Worksheet
Dim strFile As String

Set shtTarget = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MASTER - Formatted")
strFile = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Macro").Range("C2").Value
If CStr(strFile) <> "False" Then

        Set shtSource = Workbooks.Open(strFile).Sheets(1)

        ' create range objects
        Dim rngSourceHeaders As Range: Set rngSourceHeaders = shtSource.Range("B1:S1")

        shtTarget.Activate
        With shtTarget
            Dim rngTargetHeaders As Range: Set rngTargetHeaders = .Range("K1:AA1") '.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Dim rngPastePoint As Range: Set rngPastePoint = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1) 'Shoots up from the bottom of the sheet untill it bumps into something and steps one down
        End With

Dim rngDataColumn As Range

        ' process data
        Dim cl As Range, i As Integer
        For Each cl In rngTargetHeaders ' loop through each cell in target header row


            ' identify source location
            shtSource.Activate
            i = 0 ' reset I
            On Error Resume Next ' ignore errors, these are where the value can't be found and will be tested later
                i = Application.Match(cl.Value, rngSourceHeaders, 0) 'Finds the matching column name
            On Error GoTo 0 ' switch error handling back off

            ' report if source location not found
            If i = 0 Then
                intErrCount = intErrCount + 1
                Debug.Print "unable to locate item [" & cl.Value & "] at " & cl.Address ' this reports to Immediate Window (Ctrl + G to view)
                GoTo nextCL
            End If

        ' create source data range object
            With rngSourceHeaders.Cells(1, i)
                Set rngDataColumn = Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(1000000, 1).End(xlUp))
            End With

            ' pass to target range object
            shtTarget.Activate
            cl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngDataColumn.Rows.Count, rngDataColumn.Columns.Count).Value = rngDataColumn.Value

nextCL:
        Next cl

        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        shtSource.Activate
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False


        Else

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

        MsgBox "No valid file selected", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Copy Error"


End If

End Sub
```

Currently my code works perfectly fine if my master sheet only has the header and no existing data on it. If I run this code it will paste all the new data under matching columns from row 2 (row 1 is header).

But it does not append to the last existing row which is my desired output.

I have 20000 rows approx currently in master data set and I need to append new data from row 20001 for instance.

Would appreciate some help with this code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this line:

```
cl.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngDataColumn.Rows.Count, rngDataColumn.Columns.Count).Value = rngDataColumn.Value
```

Needs to take the last used row, it is currently offset by 1 from the header row.

Comment: Oh I see your point. Could you tell me if I'm able to find last row within Offset?

Comment: .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row + 1

Comment: .Cells(.Rows.Count, c1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngDataColumn.Rows.Count, rngDataColumn.Columns.Count).Value = rngDataColumn.Value   - I do get an error when i try this. sorry but i'm new to vba

Comment: @Steffi you want cl.Offset(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row, 0).Resize(rngDataColumn.Rows.Count, rngDataColumn.Columns.Count).Value = rngDataColumn.Value that